# Who can access / see project-scoped feeds?

Tags: azure-devops

When creating a new feed in a private project there is the option to choose visibility between the whole related Azure Active Directory, the whole org and specific people.

In the official docs about project-scoped feeds it says:

> With the introduction of public feeds, we also introduced project-scoped feeds, which live inside the project that they were created in, and can only be seen when accessing the Azure Artifacts hub within that project.

How is that sentence to be understood compared to choosing the visibility (during feed creation) to be e.g. the whole organisation?
To me this sounds like although the feed is project-scoped it still can be read-accessed by any person within the organisation.

Can you help with my understanding?

Comment: Hi Marko, is there any update for this issue? Just checking in to see if my answer resolves your puzzle about `project-scope feed` and `View visibility`. If that didn't help, please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Hi. I am sorry I did not answer so far. I am very busy at the moment. But I promise I will provide an answer asap.

Comment: Great! Feel free to let me know if there's any update~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the introduction of public feeds, we also introduced
>   project-scoped feeds, which live inside the project that they were
>   created in, and can only be seen when accessing the Azure Artifacts
>   hub within that project.

It means if we create a project-scoped feed `FeedA` in project `ProjectA`, we can't see details about FeedA when we're in another project. (Even though we're Porject Collection Admin!)

[image]

So in `ProjectB`, we can **only see** organization feed and project-scoped feeds created in **current** project. To see UI of FeedA and to manage its settings, we have to navigate to project `ProjectA`.

> How is that sentence to be understood compared to choosing the
>   visibility (during feed creation) to be e.g. the whole organisation?

The visibility during creation here actually represents the permissions about [Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/views?view=azure-devops#views-and-upstream-sources).

When you choose visibility `Members of current organization`:

[image]

When you choose visibility `Specific people`:

[image]

Now just like the document says, to see the details about the feed we have to navigate to the project where the feed is created. Let me share an example for better understanding:

1.I'm member of ProjectC with [project reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-security-roles?view=azure-devops) role:

[image]

2.In ProjectC I created feed FeedC with `visibility: Any members in current organization`

3.Now I'm the member of current project=> I can see the FeedC in ProjectC. Also the `View` permissions are FeedUser+MemberInOrganization, so I can see the packages in FeedC with `@Local` View.

4.Edit the view to make the view's visibility to be `Specific people`:

[image]

5.I'm the member of current project=>I can see/access the FeedC=>But I can't see packages with @Local view in FeedC any more. That's it!

**Summary:**

Project-scoped feed determines that we can't **see** the feed in another project. (We must navigate to one project to see the Feed in UI page.) Visibility determines that even when I'm member of that project, I can't see part of the packages if the view permissions is set `specific people`.

Ps: ProjectSamples is the name of my test organization...

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand it.